# Multiple component properties within the same class, accessing one of them triggers a full select

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I've a class which have different properties each of them is mapped to a different complex type (component). The problem is that when I try to access one of those properties, NHibernate causes to fetch columns of the other component as well, although lazy load is enabled for both properties.

```
var user = _session.Load<User>(userId);
user.PasswordInfo.Password; /* This causes to load other properties from another
       component property, e.g. user.MemebershipInfo.IsOnline */
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: `What I'm missing?` - to show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

Lazy properties are loaded all at once. The idea behind this feature is that you will use it mostly for blob properties, or groups of properties that are unused in most workflows.

That is a good thing. Otherwise, a class with multiple lazy properties would get many DB calls just to display the values of those properties.